# h2o basic parse file

Tags: java, h2o

I am new to h2o. I am using h2o-3.10.4.2 on Windows 7, java 1.8. I am using h2o flow. Just going through the k-modes demo. If I import seeds_dataset.txt     file from https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/00236/ and try to parse it then at record number 8, parser fails to capture column 7 and 8. This is most probably due to 2 tabs. I want the parser to consider any white spaces as a separator. Please note that if i use "http://s3.amazonaws.com/h2o-public-test-data/smalldata/flow_examples/seeds_dataset.txt" then i do not face any issues as tabs are sorted out.

So finally i want to know that when i use parseFiles in h2o how do i set any whitespaces as separator. i tried using startoftext etc but i am not able to get all the columns.

Answer (score 2):

The data is small so a quick solution to this would be to remove the double \t's in the file prior to ingesting. There are many ways to do this, here is a quick and dirty one:

```
import io
f = open("seeds_dataset.txt")
s = list(f.read())
for i in range(0,len(s)-1):
    if s[i] == '\t' and s[i+1] == '\t':
        s[i+1] = ''

output = open("seeds_dataset_fixed.txt", 'w+')
output.write("".join(s))

import h2o
h2o.init()
h2o.import_file("seeds_dataset_fixed.txt")
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Hey Nick, though this works and can be used. I wanted to achieve the same using the h2o Flow alone.

Answer (score 1):

I followed Flow's suggested parse setup and it worked fine (found the \t separator and 8 columns) - no manual intervention needed. Can you compare your steps with these please?

```
importFiles [ "https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/00236/seeds_dataset.txt" ]

setupParse source_frames: [ "https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/00236/seeds_dataset.txt" ]

parseFiles
  source_frames: ["https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/00236/seeds_dataset.txt"]
  destination_frame: "seeds_dataset1.hex"
  parse_type: "CSV"
  separator: 9
  number_columns: 8
  single_quotes: false
  column_names: null
  column_types: ["Numeric","Numeric","Numeric","Numeric","Numeric","Numeric","Numeric","Numeric"]
  delete_on_done: true
  check_header: -1
  chunk_size: 4194304
```

This is the view from 
    getFrameSummary "seeds_dataset1.hex"

Clicked on 'View Data":

```
Row C1  C2  C3  C4  C5  C6  C7  C8
1   15.2600 14.8400 0.8710  5.7630  3.3120  2.2210  5.2200  1.0
2   14.8800 14.5700 0.8811  5.5540  3.3330  1.0180  4.9560  1.0
3   14.2900 14.0900 0.9050  5.2910  3.3370  2.6990  4.8250  1.0
etc.
```

Comment: hey Arno, Other than your step 1 have followed, same steps as you have. Can you check the "missing" under "column summaries" in "seeds_dataset1.hex".  I am not able to import in h20 flow from web, hence i saved the file. I get same result as before. h20 is able to identify 8 columns. But check out row 8 and 36.